# Accessing a word from nested tuple using python programing

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested, tuples, braces

```
l = [("cat",("ball",("home","run",("jar","bin",))),"gam","glob"),"rate",("cat","bin","cat",("cat","fox","bin",("cat")))]
```

I have a list(`l`), that contains a nested tuple like in the example above. I need to access the 'cat','bin' from this `l`. How can I do this using python?

Comment: Please add an expected output, otherwise it's hard to tell what are you exactly asking.

Comment: `l[0][1][1][2][1]` ?

Comment: i need to get ('cat' position 0, 'cat' position ...,, ';cat' position ...,'bin' position ...,'bin' position ...,) the element along with the index values i wanted from this list.and the open,close braces positions.